# JavaScript and CSS minifier not working in Servicestack

Tags: javascript, css, servicestack, servicestack-razor

In the latest version of Servicestack, [minifier](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML%2C-CSS-and-JavaScript-Minification) was introduced. So, tried them in project. I am able to minify razor pages but not the javascript or css file I am adding into them.

I have copy pasted the code

```
public override List<IVirtualPathProvider> GetVirtualPathProviders()
{
    var existingProviders = base.GetVirtualPathProviders();
    var memFs = new InMemoryVirtualPathProvider(this);

    //Get existing Local FileSystem Provider
    var fs = existingProviders.First(x => x is FileSystemVirtualPathProvider);

    //Process all .html files:
    foreach (var file in fs.GetAllMatchingFiles("*.html"))
    {
        var contents = Minifiers.HtmlAdvanced.Compress(file.ReadAllText());
        memFs.AddFile(file.VirtualPath, contents);
    }

    //Process all .css files:
    foreach (var file in fs.GetAllMatchingFiles("*.css")
      .Where(file => !file.VirtualPath.EndsWith(".min.css"))) //ignore pre-minified .css
    {
        var contents = Minifiers.Css.Compress(file.ReadAllText());
        memFs.AddFile(file.VirtualPath, contents);
    }

    //Process all .js files
    foreach (var file in fs.GetAllMatchingFiles("*.js")
      .Where(file => !file.VirtualPath.EndsWith(".min.js"))) //ignore pre-minified .js
    {
        try
        {
            var js = file.ReadAllText();
            var contents = Minifiers.JavaScript.Compress(js);
            memFs.AddFile(file.VirtualPath, contents);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //As JSMin is a strict subset of JavaScript, this can fail on valid JS.
            //We can report exceptions in StartUpErrors so they're visible in ?debug=requestinfo
            base.OnStartupException(new Exception("JSMin Error {0}: {1}".Fmt(file.VirtualPath, ex.Message)));
        }
    }

    //Give new Memory FS the highest priority
    existingProviders.Insert(0, memFs);
    return existingProviders;
}
```

And while debugging it I found out that. It is indeed minifying the files but some how it is not getting there in out put.

I have also tried debug and release and even with deployed version. But JavaScript and CSS that are I am adding there as reference are still in beutified format only.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please be more specific about what doesn't work? i.e. What request (e.g. which file) is not getting the output? (please provide HTTP Request/Response headers) and did the specific file minify successfully? Can you post the HTTP Request and Response of what's not working, also are there any StartUp Exceptions reported in `?debug=requestinfo` ?

Comment: @mythz I guess its my bad  on this end. In chrome console jQuery and Bootstrap for both js and css files are shown as beutified but when I did view source and open js file in  browser it is minified only.

But weirdly in console also js file I wrote app.js and app.css both are showing minified version and I seriously don't know why.

There is no error catch in the process.